# Using catchError() inside the pipe() shows an error at the .subscribe variable

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

I wanted to handle the errors for a method in angular. I read that I can use the catchError() inside of the .pipe(). 
When I added an catchError check I get the variable `roomId` marked with the red squiggly line, which says `TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'`

This is the part where I do the error check.

```
this.firstRoom(room).pipe(
        first(), 
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse)=>{
             if(error.status != 200){
               // handle error
             }else{
               // return error
               return throwError(error);
            }
         }),
```

And here is the complete method.

```
public findRoom(room: Room): Observable<house> {
    return new Observable(house => {
      this.firstRoom(room).pipe(
        first(), 
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse)=>{
                  if(error.status != 200){
                    // handle error
                  }else{
                    // return error
                    return throwError(error);
                  }
                }),
      ).subscribe(roomId => 
        this.gointToThisRoom(roomId).pipe( <----- roomId throws that argument type unknown
          first()
        ).subscribe(roomInfo => {
            if (roomInfo.status === "failed") {
              house.next(house.failed);
            } else {
              this.downloadRoom(roomId).pipe(
                first()
              ).subscribe(blobFile =>
                this.getRoom(blobFile, name)
              );
              house.next(house.ready)
            }
          }
        )
      )
    });
  }
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`catchError` expects you to return an observable, which can be `throwError` or, if you handled it, a new observable as a fallback value.

In your case you could do something like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

...

```
catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  if (error.status != 200) {
    // handle error and use any value you like to return if that's your goal.
    // This could be anything, like a number, string or an object, depending on your use-case.
    const fallbackValue: Room = { properties... };
    return of(fallbackValue); // You will get this in your subscription callback
  } else {
    // return error
    return throwError(error);
  }
}),
```

Comment: This solved the unknown type error, but then I got another error, it doesn't know the type of `roomInfo.status` error: `Property 'status' does not exist on type 'any[] `

Comment: it should return an Observable<house>

Comment: this.firstRoom() returns an Observable<number> so roomId is a number

Comment: now it works I don't get the error anymore and I don't know why... I wrote the same code again

Comment: @dernor00 I clarified a bit and will remove above comments ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `new Observable` constructor with subscription inside a subscription. It's hard to follow the logic, and you can't simply cancel pending operations by unsubscribing.
2. And `// handle error` should actually handle error.

I'd do something like this:

```
public findRoom(room: Room): Observable < house > {
    return this.firstRoom(room).pipe(
        first(),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (error.status != 200) {
                return EMPTY;
            } else {
                // return error
                return throwError(error);
            }
        }),
        switchMap(roomId => this.gointToThisRoom(roomId)),
        first(),
        // ... the rest of the pipe
    );
}
```

Comment: If I return the this.firstRoom the return types mismatch

Comment: You need to implement `// ... the rest of the pipe`. Also, knowing more about the typings used here will be helpful.